# Is there any way to determine which series a given GraphDataItem comes from?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using AmCharts to plot two lines on a line chart. They have [some great documentation](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/updating-balloon-tool-tip-text-fly/) on how to use a function to customize the "balloon" (tooltip) text. However, it's not clear how I would go about distinguishing between the two data series in this custom function. At first glance it doesn't seem like there's any property in the [GraphDataItem object](http://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/GraphDataItem) to identify which series the data comes from.

Here's some pseduo code, for visual people:

```
graph.balloonFunction = adjustBalloonText;

function adjustBalloonText(graphDataItem, graph) {
    if ( graphDataItem ...series?... == 1 ) {
        return "something";
    } else {
        return "something else";
    }
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check GraphDataItem description:
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/GraphDataItem

It has a "category" property, also a reference to serialDataItem: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/SerialDataItem

Which contains all the information about series.

And finally, it has a reference to original data item from data provider (dataContext property). So you can store additional information in your data and then get it using dataContext.